# Got a problem with the last encounter in Undertale

Tags: undertale

I think i might have done something wrong.
I went into mettaton's room with having 1 encounter left and so i thought that was the last encounter.
I did the 3 encounters that are in the bridge in the area and also 20 encounters in hotlands.
My friend knew about it but they forgot so now i accidentally did pacifist.
I sadly didn't know that mettaton isn't last encounter.. So i might reset or do i keep trying?

Answer (score 1):

If you still can, reload your save, otherwise you will have to reset and do everything over again...

Comment: i really wouldn't want to reset because it would take a long time but i think i have to!

Comment: it has been designed to push you towards neutral (not actually pacifist xD) at any possible point, so this is by design. it is not meant to be fun, or even to be completed unless you are really determined. In some regions you can only easily get encounters in some open spots, so best to just go farming there until you get to zero, then go to the boss. After the boss you don't have any options any more.

Comment: The accident i did is fight Mettaton NEO before the last encounter so i think that's why i can't get it anymore and i went in the house.Instead of flowey encountering me i got the different enemies: Froggit,whismalott ect.

Comment: Also, it still says "1 left" so do i reset or keep trying? i might have 1 hotlands encounter left or Core.

Comment: If it still says 1 left, you can actually go to a region to farm and probably still make it. As far as I know, Hotland and Core count as one region together for the game. But as far as I know, after the boss they don't spawn anymore. Don't hold your breath but worth trying...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to go for the Genocide ending and corrupt your save file. After Mettaton, continue walking about a few areas you have been in before that fight until you finish off the last monster. If it says "but nobody came" when you try to start a battle then you're good to go. Try your best not to hack the game like I did.